# Why doesn't z-index work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a web application and I'm having trouble with one part, where I have a rollover thing, but it's currently rolling under. EDIT: pastehtml was rejected, here is jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XmKwt/1/

The right div goes under the left div, even though the z-index says it should not.

I have found that if the "position:relative;" css is removed (see source) then it works just fine, but I don't understand why and I need the "position:relative;" css there for other reasons, not demonstrated in this simplified example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    /* Remove this line and it works */

    #featureleft {position:relative;}

    /* End */

    #layoutdiv { text-align: left; width: 940px; }
    #featureleft { width: 580px; float: left;z-index:10; background:red; }
    #featureright { float: right; z-index:100;}
    #copypaste { background-color: #bbb; margin-bottom: 40px; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; width: 300px; height:200px; margin-left: 20px; border: solid 5px #000; }
    </style>

    <script language='javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#copypaste').mouseenter(function(){
            p=$(this).position();
            // increase/move by p.left
            move=Math.round(p.left)-0;
            width=parseInt($(this).css('width'))+parseInt(move);
            margin=0-(parseInt(move)-20);
            inputs=parseInt(move)+280;
            $(this).css('width',width+'px').css('margin-left',margin+'px').css('height',$(this).height);
        });

        $('#copypaste').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css('width','300px');
            $(this).css('margin-left','20px');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="layoutdiv" class='container fakewindowcontain'>
        <div id='featurewrapper'>
            <div id='featureleft'>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut eget et enim, nec auctor habitasse eu mattis eget odio, lacinia vivamus libero dictum, tempor nunc nec nam fringilla mauris, et class dolor curabitur ipsum. Commodo ultricies id</p>
            </div>

            <div id='featureright'>
                <div id='copypaste'>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut eget et enim, nec auctor habitasse eu mattis eget odio, lacinia vivamus libero dictum, tempor nunc nec nam fringilla mauris, et class dolor curabitur ipsum. Commodo ultricies id</p>
                </div>      
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: High Risk Website Blocked
Location: pastehtml.com/view/bwqlq812t.html
Access has been blocked as the threat Mal/HTMLGen-A has been found on this website.

Comment: Your pastehtml link doesn't work. For what it's worth, the CSS z-index  property is ignored on elements that don't have a position other than static (the default).

Comment: Your link is also not working for me. You should try http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @Diodeus same here, I edited out the link.  BenHolness please post the code in the question.  The link you provided is showing as malicious.

Comment: Link works for me but basically yes, "the CSS z-index property is ignored on elements that don't have a position other than static (the default)." is somewhat an answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The #featureright div does not have a position declared (and thus it is the same as position: static). As I said in my comment

> "the CSS z-index property is ignored on elements that don't have a
>   position other than static (the default)"

Therefore, to get it to obey the z-index property, you need to add position: relative to #featureright

Comment: EDIT: But if you add position: relative, you're mouseenter function doesn't work unless you change p = $(this).position() to p = $(this).offset()...but that's a whole lot of messy code anyway...

Comment: adding position:relative to #featureright stops the rollover from working though. I guess I need to find a different way to make that happen.

Comment: Just add `position: relative` and `z-index:100` to `#copypaste` instead of `#featureright`